# Using same partial for different objects in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a partial for post named _post.html.haml which I want to use for rendering two objects @posts and @Bposts.

It works great with @posts but I can't use this to render @Bposts.
Here is the code. This is working

```
= render partial: 'posts/post',collection: @posts
```

But this is not working

```
= render partial: 'posts/post', object: @Bposts, as: 'post'
```

I have tried different solutions but nothing worked. I don't want to duplicate the entire partial.

Comment: Try changing `object: @Bposts` to `collection: @Bposts`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked great :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this

```
<%= render partial; "posts/post", locals: {post: @post} %>
```

This will then treat post as a local variable, e.g.

```
<%= post.name %>
```

Inside the partial.

---

A word of warning, I would advise against this approach. You may find that your two models diverge and need to be displayed differently. If this happens it is easier and cleaner to use two partials instead of adapting that one with a lot of conditional statements.